# Pan-able view not staying where I pan it using UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to use a UIPanGestureRecognizer to move an object around the screen. My panning code seems to work fine. I can move my object around with ease. But when I let go of the object it snaps back to its original position; it doesn't stay where I pan it.

The pan-able object is a simple UIView, and it's being moved around in my main self.view field. I added the UIPanGesture using the objects palate in XCode, not manually in code in viewDidLoad for example.

In state = began, I apply a transform to bump the scale up slightly. (This ALSO doesn't appear to be working, but that's another story).

Can anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
- (IBAction)bucketTouch:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
switch ([recognizer state]) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
            self.pail.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.25, 1.25);
        }];
    }
        break;

    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:{
        CGPoint centerPoint = self.pail.center;
        CGPoint newPoint = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
        CGPoint finalPoint = CGPointMake(centerPoint.x + newPoint.x, centerPoint.y + newPoint.y);
        self.pail.center = finalPoint;
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
    }
        break;

    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:{
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.pail]; 
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
            self.pail.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }];
    }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the view WAS indeed moving properly, but the CGAffineTransformIdentity was placing it back to its original frame position upon recognizer.state = ended.